# How to refresh a component when it becomes visible in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 4.3.0 application the header,left and right panel are hidden in the login page.
They become visible only when the login is successful.
The problem is that when the components become visible the data is not pre loaded.
The ngOnInit method is called when they are first loaded and this results in lots of errors as the data has not properly loaded before login

How can i resolve this as i want to load the components or refresh them once login is successful.

Below is the App-Component.html

```
<loading-bar color="#FF0000" [height]="3" [animationTime]="0.3" [runInterval]="100" [progress]="0"></loading-bar>
<div class="app app-header-fixed" value="test">
    <app-header *ngIf="header"></app-header>

    <app-left-menu *ngIf="leftmenu"></app-left-menu>
    <div id="content" class="app-content plain_wraper" role="main">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <app-right-menu *ngIf="rightmenu"></app-right-menu>

</div>
```

For example in the app-header component inside the ngOnInit method we get the profile of the user

```
this.userProfile = this.userServ.getUserProfile();
```

But this wont load and gives errors.
So how can i get this profile data to load once the component is visible?

Should i subscribe to the visiblity params and load profile once the component is visible?

Thanks!

Comment: `this wont load and gives errors` .....what errors?

Comment: Can you also provide the `getUserProfile()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call `ngOnInit` a method. Its a life-cycle hook and in it you call methods.

But from what I see, you probably need to initialize data in `ngAfterViewInit` hook. So:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
 this.userProfile = this.userServ.getUserProfile();
}
```

Comment: Thank You ! That helped.